# Tomcat integrated with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have configured a Tomcat instance within the Eclipse workspace for debugging my web application.

Is there any way to configure or control the activities of the Tomcat instance, outside the Eclipse environment or through any (script or code)?

[Note:- I am trying to create an ant script, to combine the activities like stop the server, copy the source code from version control system, compile the updated source, redeploy it in the eclipse integrated server path and restart the server. Your inputs will help me a lot!!]

Thanks in advance.!!!

[Tomcat integrated with Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaNrb.png)

Comment: It depends, what OS are you running?

Comment: http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ant` can perform all these actions for you. As far as the startup/stopping of the server is concerned, Tomcat includes classes to manipulate these actions from ant found in the `{YOUR_TOMCAT_HOME}/server/lib/catalina-ant.jar`.

The ant-tasks should look like this (excert from [this link](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/ant/how-to-control-start-and-stop-of-a-tomcat-application-by-ant-build-s-2.html)):

Suppose name of your application name is newapp then in your build.xml include following.

```
<property name="name" value="newapp"/>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
<classpath>
<path location="${appserver.home}/server/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
</classpath> 
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
<classpath>
<path location="${appserver.home}/server/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/> 
</classpath>
</taskdef>
<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
<start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
password="${tomcat.manager.password }"
path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
<stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
username="${ tomcat.manager.username}"
password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
path="/${name}"/>
</target>
```

And make a file build.properties which contains variables used by build.xml

```
# Ant properties for building the springapp
appserver.home=${user.home}/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28
deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=admin 
tomcat.manager.password=tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it with an Ant-Script. Just write a script that, compiles your webapp, then package the whole application with the `WAR`-Target. Stop the tomcat via the `Exec`-Target, copy the war-file and start the tomcat again with the `Exec`-Target.

If you've installed your tomcat as a service you can use the windows command 
`net stop "tomcatServiceName"` to stop your tomcat.
e.g.

```
<target name="stop-tomcat6">
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg line='/c net stop "Apache Tomcat"'/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: i hope this doesn't work. if there is a tomcat service running in our task manager, we can stop as you have mentioned. if you use tomcat integrated with eclipse, you can't see a tomcat service running behind!!! is there any other option.?

Comment: If you use tomcat inside eclipse why don't you deploy directly within eclipse?

Comment: i am trying to integrate the server startup/shutdown activity with the build process.